# Why compiler is not able to optimize read from TLS?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, thread-local-storage

Consider follwing header file, "tls.h":

```
#include <stdint.h>

// calling this function is expensive
uint64_t foo(uint64_t x);

extern __thread uint64_t cache;

static inline uint64_t
get(uint64_t x)
{
    // if cache is not valid
    if (cache == UINT64_MAX)
        cache = foo(x);

    return cache + x;
}
```

and source file "tls.c":

```
#include "tls.h"

__thread uint64_t cache = {0};

uint64_t foo(uint64_t x)
{
    // imagine some calculations are performed here
    return 0;
}
```

Below is example usage of `get()` function in "main.c":

```
#include "tls.h"

uint64_t t = 0;

int main()
{
    uint64_t x = 0;

    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < 1024UL * 1024 * 1024; i++){
        t += get(i);
        x++;
    }
}
```

Presented files are compiled as following:

```
gcc -c -O3 tls.c
gcc -c -O3 main.c
gcc -O3 main.o tls.o
```

Examining the performance of loop in "main.c" revealed that compiler optimization is very poor. After disassembling the binary, it is clear that tls is being accessed in every iteration. 
Execution time on my machine is 1.7s.

However, if I remove check for cache validity in `get()` method so that it looks like this:

```
static inline uint64_t
get(uint64_t x)
{
    return cache + x;
}
```

the compiler is now able to create much faster code - it completely removes the loop and generates only only one "add" instruction. Execution time is ~0.02s.

Why the compiler is not able to optimize the first case? TLS variable cannot be changed by other threads so compiler should be able to optimize this, right?

Is there any other way I can optimize the `get()` function?

Comment: It is totally possible for a thread to take the address of a TLS variable and “publish” it to other threads, which could then write to it. So no, the compiler cannot optimize the access out, and 1.7s is not poor: It’s about what you’d expect for 1e9 TLS accesses.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist ok, but then why the second case is optimized? there is also a TLS access, just not in the `if`

Comment: In the second case, foo() is unused, and literally everything the program does is available to the compiler in one translation unit, main.c (with the exception of `cache`’s initializer, 0, from tls.o). The compiler can then optimize into one access to TLS, multiplied by 1e9, and strength-reduce the loop of summations of incrementing values into a scalar addition.

Comment: Are you sure tls.o is unused? Notice that `cache` is declared as extern variable and is defined in tls.c

Comment: I edited my comment a minute ago to walk the part about tls.o back, if you refresh you’ll see

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist "_take the address (...) could then write to it_" So you have established that a thread local variable is pretty much a normal object with a short name (instead of `global_thread_map[current_thread].var`). You have not established that the compiler must support concurrent access by other threads for a normal object.

Comment: Many things new and thread related are treated like opaque function call or opaque `asm` statement by many compilers. Not even the most simple sequence of operations on atomic variables are simplified by arithmetic rules (like `x++; x++;` transformed to `x+=2`). Many things thread related are effectively treated like volatile objects for the purpose of code optimizations, which is just dumb.